# Evaluate two datasets for corresponding to given pairwise matching

Tags: clustering, paired-data, agreement-statistics, metric

Suppose I have two matched $N \times D$ datasets $X$ and $Y$. The samples are in matched order (with $n$th sample in $X$ being the same object as the $n$th sample in $Y$). The features are (or at least, should be) in the same "space". I am looking for a metric that measures the extent to which this is actually the case.

I'm planning an approach that treats each pair as a cluster. In other words, I would concatenate $X$ and $Y$ into a $2N \times D$ matrix, and define the cluster labeling with $N$ unique cluster labels for each pair. I could then use clustering metrics that take in data and a cluster labeling, and then output their "agreement", such as the Calinski-Harabasz index (Variance Ratio Criterion) or the Silhouette Coefficient.

Is there a better approach?

Edit: I am looking for a metric that indicates whether $X$ and $Y$ contain the same representations of the paired samples. In general the metric should be "large" when $X=Y$, though it would be bad if this were achieved trivially with $X=Y=0$. If $Y_{nd} = X_{nd} + \epsilon_{nd}, \epsilon_{nd} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, then the metric should ideally go down when $\sigma$ goes up. If $Y = X M$, then the metric should ideally go down the "further" $M$ is from $I_d$, even if $M$ is orthogonal. Ideally, I would like a metric $m$ where $m(X, Y) = m(2X, 2Y)$, but $m(X, 2X) \ne 0$. The metric should ideally be easy to understand and explain to others, and one that is already commonly-used in statistics and therefore easy to justify to others.

Comment: The possible answers are limitless, so please tell us more specifically what this metric is intended to accomplish or how you will interpret it.

Comment: @whuber -- I've clarified my desiderata.

Comment: This looks like you want to measure agreement, so have a look at the tag [tag:agreement-statistics], maybe add it?